# Duration and work concerning tasks in MS Project

Tags: ms-project, project-planning

i have a problem in MS Project 2013:

i´d like to set up a work package that has a certain duration but in this duration there is no work like 8 hours x (duration in days) required but e.g. 5 days of work in a timeframe of 30 days.

this is annoying to set up but it works. now ms project does not draw the respective bar for 30 days of duration but only for 5 days (the work). at the end of the bar a little arrows goes on for another 25 days (resulting in 5+25=30days) and then turns down to the next work package. i´d rather like to see a bar for the full 30 days and then for the arrow to go down.

is there a way to do this?

it seems wrong that the bar depends on the work rather than the duration because it is not likely that the work gets done in the first 5 days and then you just wait for 25 days.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new task and set the Duration to 30d and make sure the type is "Fixed Duration" and set the task's Work to 40h.